# Конкретизация шаблонного класса с помощью typedef

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++

Есть шаблонный класс `A` и из него я хочу сделать 2 конкретных: `B` и `C`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<const char* s = "hello">
class A {
public:
    void foo();
};

template<const char* s>
void A<s>::foo() {
    cout << s;
}

typedef A<" world"> B;

class C : public A<"!\n"> {};

int main() {
    A<"hello"> a;
    B b;
    C c;
    a.foo();
    b.foo();
    c.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

но получаю ошибку:

```
prog.cpp:15:19: error: ‘" world"’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘const char*’ because string literals can never be used in this context
 typedef A<" world"> B;
                   ^
prog.cpp:17:25: error: ‘"!\012"’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘const char*’ because string literals can never be used in this context
 class C : public A<"!\n"> {};
                         ^
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:20:11: error: ‘"hello"’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘const char*’ because string literals can never be used in this context
  A<"hello"> a;
           ^
prog.cpp:23:4: error: request for member ‘foo’ in ‘a’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
  a.foo();
    ^~~
prog.cpp:24:4: error: request for member ‘foo’ in ‘b’, which is of non-class type ‘B {aka int}’
  b.foo();
    ^~~
prog.cpp:25:4: error: ‘class C’ has no member named ‘foo’
  c.foo();
    ^~~
```

[Код на ideone.](http://ideone.com/AJqfhH)

Если у `A` в шаблоне вместо строки целое число, то код прекрасно работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании нетипизированных шаблонных аргументов (template non-type arguments) есть ряд [ограничений](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters), среди которых:

> For pointers to objects, the template arguments have to designate the
>   address of an object with static storage duration and a linkage
>   (either internal or external), or a constant expression that evaluates
>   to the appropriate null pointer or std::nullptr_t value.

Это ограничение приводит к тому, что строковые литералы в качестве аргументов шаблона использовать нельзя:

> In particular, this implies that string literals, addresses of array elements, and addresses of non-static members cannot be used as template arguments to instantiate templates whose corresponding non-type template parameters are pointers to objects.

Поскольку они не обладают ни внутренней, ни внешней линковкой. Это значит, что стандарт не гарантирует размещение идентичных строковых литералов по одному и тому же адресу, оставляя выбор реализации разработчикам компиляторов. Поэтому  использование `A<"hello"> a;` в разных фрагментах кода могло бы привести к инстанциированию различных шаблонов.

---

Разобравшись с причиной ошибки, можно попробовать её устранить: нам необходимо передать в качестве аргумента шаблона указатель на объект со статической продолжительностью хранения и внутренней или внешней линковкой.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<const char* s>
class A {
    public:
        void foo() {
            cout << s << "\n";
        }
};

extern const char p[];
const char p[] = "earth";

extern const char str[];
const char str[] = "world";

template<>
class A<str> {
    public:
        void foo() {
            cout << "partial specialization: " << str << "\n";
        }
};

using B = A<str>;

int main() {
    A<p> a;
    B b;
    a.foo();
    b.foo();
    return 0;
}
```